# Variable ${project.version} in maven-checkstyle-plugin comes from child projekt

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I have project with **camel parent**.

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.1</version>
   </parent>

 <groupId>my.project</groupId>
 <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
 <name>myArtifact</name>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 ...
```

When I run

```
mvn checkstyle:check
```

I receive:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (default-cli) on project demo: 
Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check failed: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Could not find artifact org.apache.camel:camel-buildtools:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

1.0.0-SNAPSHOT comes from my project version = 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

This is part off **camel-parent-2.23.1.pom**

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin-version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
              <artifactId>camel-buildtools</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>${maven-checkstyle-version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

I suppose that **mvn checkstyle:check**  have to use camel version(2.23.1) as project.version.

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build the child project, `${project.version}$` is the version number of the child project. A property cannot have different values depending on whether the definition is in the parent or the child POM.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't use camel as a parent, I have to use it as dependency?

Comment: I don't know how to use apache camel, but the camel-parent seems like an internal parent POM, not meant to be used by users of apache camel.